# Struct returning Void in Alamofire responseJSON understanding

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm busy looking into the Alamofire networking library that has been created for Swift. I have come across the responseJSON function:

```
public func responseJSON(
        queue queue: dispatch_queue_t? = nil,
        options: NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments,
        completionHandler: Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void)
        -> Self
    {
        return response(
            queue: queue,
            responseSerializer: Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: options),
            completionHandler: completionHandler
        )
    }
```

My question is straight forward, what does `Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void` mean? Does this line mean the completion handler for the `responseJSON` method takes a function type of type `Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void`? If that were the case should it have been `(Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void`?

I'm new to swift and from the Swift syntax, it leads me to believe that the `Response` struct itself is returning Void and that `Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void` is not a function type but rather just a Void function.

Could someone please clear this up for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is a closure with a function type Response which would return nothing.

As it is a completion handler, you should pass a function which is responsible for handling the response.

it can be

```
.responseJSON({ response in 
//your logic
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the liberty to elaborate on Horst's answer because you're new to Swift. A closure is a block of code (like a function really) that will be executed at some point in the code. So when you write `Alamofire.request(###).responseJSON(completionHandler: yourHandler)` you're telling Alamofire to launch a request and you're also giving it the code to execute once it has gotten the response from the server (because the call is asynchronous). Somewhere in Alamofire's code, when the request has completed, it will call the `completionHandler(response)` closure you've provided with the `response` parameter being of type `Response<AnyObject, NSError>`.

The `Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void` signature means your closure takes one argument you can use in your closure's code. That means Alamofire will provide you the response object which you can use inside the closure's code. The short and elegant way to write a closure in Swift is similar to what Horst wrote :

```
Alamofire.request(###).responseJSON {response in
    // Your code
    switch response {
    case .Success(let json):
        // Use the json
    case .Failure(let error):
        // Use the error
    }
}
```